# Static signature for higher order function in Bigloo Scheme

Tags: scheme, bigloo

Does anyone know how to create a static signature for a higher order function in the module export section in the Bigloo Scheme language?

Here is how far I got

```
(module test
  (export (adder ::double)))

(define (adder x)
  (lambda (y)
    (set! x (+ x y))
    x))
```

The following will work, but I want to keep all the type data in the module declaration

```
(module test
  (export (adder ::double)))

(define (adder x)
  (lambda (y::double)::double
    (set! x (+ x y))
    x))
```

Comment: I think you have better chances getting an answer on the Bigloo mailing list: http://www-sop.inria.fr/indes/fp/Bigloo/bigloo.html#Mailing-list