# Bigloo: Type-hinting a function argument

Tags: function, scheme, type-hinting, bigloo

Suppose I have a procedure called `foo`, which returns a `::float` which is meant to take the following arguments:

1. A procedure taking two `::float` arguments.
2. A `::float`
3. Another `::float`

How would I write an `export` for that function in the `module` part of the code? I have this so far:

```
(module bar
    (export (foo::float 'something ::float ::float)))
```

What should `'something` be replaced by here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is similar to [a previous bigloo question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100256/static-signature-for-higher-order-function-in-bigloo-scheme). There is currently no elegant way to do this. You should use ::procedure as the type of the first argument. This is no dramatic loss, because - in many cases - bigloo's type inference and flow analysis will find the errors you are trying to capture with type annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Without actually testing here is my guess.

Define a type, say, `fun-of-two-floats` using `type`.

The example in the docs is:

```
(module foo 
   (extern
    (type *string->double
          (function double (string)) 
                    "double (*)(char *)")
    (macro cv::*string->double "convert")))

(print (*string->double-call cv "3.14"))
```

So my guess is that this will work:

```
(type fun-of-two-floats
      (function float (float float)))

(module bar
    (export (foo::float fun-of-two-floats ::float ::float)))
```

Docs are here: http://www-sop.inria.fr/mimosa/fp/Bigloo/doc/bigloo-28.html#Defining-an-extern-type

Comment: Please note that type definitions are for external types (i.e. C, not Scheme).

Comment: Okay. My answer should be ignored then.